# Ruby search in http get request response body

Tags: ruby, https, xmlhttprequest, web-crawler

I'am making a get request in ruby like;

```
    require 'net/http'
    require 'uri'

    uri = URI.parse("https://www.test.com")
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
    request.content_type = "application/json"
    request["Accept"] = "application/json"

    req_options = {
      use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
    }

    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
      http.request(request)
    end

    # response.code
    response.body
```

This is a html source return plain text. I would like to search for some id element on this return and get its value. It seems as a crawler. but I have never written one.

For instance, there is a field like;

```
<div id='price'>1000€</div>
```

I would like to search for `<div id='price'>` and get 1000€.

I can only get its index. But then do not know what should i do.

Is it possible ? or is there any other way?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri gem.

> Nokogiri (鋸) is a Rubygem providing HTML, XML, SAX, and Reader parsers
>   with XPath and CSS selector support.

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<HTML
<div id="block1">
    <a href="http://google.com">link1</a>
</div>
<div id="block2">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">link2</a>
    <a id="tips">just a bookmark</a>
</div>
HTML

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.css('#block1 a[href]').text
#=>link1
```

To modify your example:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'nokogiri'
uri = URI.parse("https://www.example.com")
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request.content_type = "application/json"
request["Accept"] = "application/json"

req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end

response.body

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(response.body)

doc.css('p').text;
#=> "This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this\n    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.More information..."
```

Comment: Working fine... Thank you.